# How to click a button on my Django Interface and start a python script

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, web-applications

I am working on my first webapp using Django (Python 3), and I have a python script that already plots data using matplotlib with no problem. However I want to place a button in a webapp to simply trigger my plotting script to run. I have looked for tutorials online, but they are mostly unclear and only show css options and javascript options. If it's possible, is there a way to do this?

My code is fairly simple right now and I am using a dummy script just for testing. I have a scripts folder in my webapp directory with the test script in it, but I can't find a way to run it.

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ####My first attempt was the line below#####
    url(r'^polls/scripts/NIA_stocks_automation.py', views.IndexView, name='chart')
]
```

index.py:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<!--my test button -->
<button id="runScript_btn" type="button" style="height:100px;width:100px" action="chart"></button>
<h1>"Le Duh"</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}

{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">
```

Below is a screenshot of the directory:

[image]

My WebApp interface:

[image]

Comment: Just create another view for your script. When that view gets the request, you run the script. It's straight-forward. And you'll also have to replace `<button>` with `<a>`.

Comment: @xyres thank you for your help, but could you give me an example? This is my first time working with webapps.

Comment: But what are you looking to achieve here? Your script runs, and then what happens? What response do you want to send back to the user? Do you want to send the output of the script back to the user or run the script in background?

Comment: @xyres I can run the web-app and the script independently, but I want to click the button html button to run the script. Right now I just run the script using command line. When I click the button now, nothing happens.

Comment: Do you care if the page refreshes? If not, just put the button inside a form and send it back to your index `/` get the post request with `request.method == "POST"` or if you're using classed based views `def post(self, request):` and call the script from your view. If you do not want to refresh look into AJAX.

Comment: @Stephen I don't mind if it refreshes currently. I'll look into ajax